Block unknown users from adding me to Messenger group chats
My Facebook account has been deactivated, but I am still on Messenger. It is referred to as a Deactivated Except Messenger Account (DEMA)
I recently received a notification that I had been added to a group chat by someone I didn't recognise or have added.
The chat contained inappropriate content and I am surprised that someone can add me to their chat without my approval.
Upon opening the notification I had two options, "delete" and "leave", both of which appear to do the same thing.
There does not seem to be an option in the app to block people I have never met from adding me to group chats.
Is there something I'm missing?

Please review the following Facebook Messenger help article and [edit] your question to advise if it addressed your  needs and if not, why not: Control who can send messages to your Messenger Chats list

This article does not answer my question as it does not concern itself with group chats.

Did you review the settings to see if there was a restriction that was unset? Image_1 Image_2 Image_3

I've changed "Others on Messenger and Facebook" to "don't receive requests". I suppose it's possible the message I received, since my options were "delete" and "leave", may technically have been viewed as a request and not a full-on chat join. I'll keep the thread updated.

Sounds good. Also note that "People with your phone number" is a low bar since nothing stops a stranger from having your phone number from a list or randomly generated.
